# Given an array of desired String in the order of their creation. Since two strings cannot be equal replace it versioning them

Tags: java, java-8

Given an array of desired String in the order of their creation. Since two strings cannot be equal , the one which comes later will have an addition to its name in a form of (k), where k is the smallest positive integer such that the obtained name is not used yet.

```
static String[] fileNaming(String[] names) {
        List<String> newNames = new ArrayList<String>();
        LinkedHashMap<String, Integer> wordCount = new LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>();
        Arrays.asList(names).stream().forEach(x -> {
            String str = x;
            if (wordCount.containsKey(x)) {
                str = x + "(" + String.valueOf(wordCount.get(x)) + ")";
                wordCount.merge(x, 1, Integer::sum);
                wordCount.merge(str, 1, Integer::sum);
            } else {
                wordCount.put(x, 1);
            }

            newNames.add(str);
            System.out.println(wordCount);
        });
    
        return newNames.toArray(new String[names.length]);
    }
```

Testing this code against two string[]'s

```
Arrays.toString(fileNaming(new String[] { "doc", "doc",
         "image", "doc(1)", "doc" }))

Arrays.toString(
                fileNaming(new String[] { "a(1)", "a(6)", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a" }))
```

The desired output for both of them should be

```
["doc", "doc(1)", "image", "doc(1)(1)", "doc(2)"].

 ["a(1)", "a(6)",  "a",  "a(2)",  "a(3)",  "a(4)", "a(5)",  "a(7)",  "a(8)",  "a(9)",  "a(10)", "a(11)"]
```

With the given code I was able to match the first output correctly. But for the second one I am getting

```
[a(1), a(6), a, a(1), a(2), a(3), a(4), a(5), a(6), a(7), a(8), a(9)]
```

Here we can see that a(1) and a(6) are being repeated. For which I have put a check but still no getting the desired output.

Comment: And how is this related to scala?

Comment: @Nosrep removed scala. Though i was aiming if this could be done in scala more easly would prefer that too.

Comment: @boilerplate.code I've read question's title 3 times, and I still can't parse what you are asking. What do you mean in *Since two strings cannot be equal*? since when strings cannot be equal? what does this -> *the one which comes later will have an addition to its name in a form of (k), where k is the smallest positive integer such that the obtained name is not used yet.* - mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you aren't checking your new files to see if they are already present. I think it can work like this:

```
static String[] fileNaming(String[] names) {
        List<String> newNames = new ArrayList<String>();
        var usedNames = new HashSet<String>();
        Arrays.asList(names).stream().forEach(x -> {
            int retries = 0;
            var uniqueName = x;
            while (!usedNames.add(uniqueName)) {
                uniqueName = x + "(" + ++retries + ")";
            }
            newNames.add(uniqueName);
            System.out.println(wordCount);
        });
    
        return newNames.toArray(new String[names.length]);
    }
```

If you have a lot of copies of the same string, this will be slower than your original code...but it is simpler and it works, so it has that going for it! You could tweak this code to be faster in that case but it probably isn't worth it (unless you know you'll get lots of copies of your strings).

Edit: Oh heck, here's the O(n) version:

```
static String[] fileNaming(String[] names) {
    List<String> newNames = new ArrayList<String>();
    var usedNames = new HashSet<String>();
    var counts = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    Arrays.asList(names).stream().forEach(x -> {
        int retries = counts.getOrDefault(x, 0);
        var uniqueName = x;
        while (!usedNames.add(uniqueName)) {
            uniqueName = x + "(" + ++retries + ")";
        }
        newNames.add(uniqueName);
        counts.put(x, retries);
        System.out.println(wordCount);
    });

    return newNames.toArray(new String[names.length]);
}
```

Comment: The problem I want it in the O(n) Since i may have a lot of copies .

Comment: To make it O(n) you need to have a map from name to integer; start retries at that integer, then step up, and save it when you find the unique name. That means that you will only have to loop over usedNames when a(5) is already created and you get your fifth "a", which I think is still O(n) because each name can at most force a loop once.

Comment: I am trying to do it using a map but unable to achieve

Comment: I edited my answer to add code that should work with O(n). I haven't tested it but it looks straightforward.